# InputStream and File Upload in Spark Java

Tags: java, spark-java

I have a java app written using spark (not the apache spark, but spark-java). I'd simply like to get a handle to the stream being posted, but not read from the stream until I do so explicitly. However, as soon as I make the call to `getInputStream()` it seems as though the entire file is being read at this point. Shouldn't that only happen if i try to read from the input stream? If i'm wrong, can any one provide guidance on how I can do something like that?

```
post("/encrypt", (req, res) -> {
        try {                
            req.attribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", new MultipartConfigElement("ProtectCS"));
            Part p = req.raw().getPart("uploaded_file");
            InputStream input = p.getInputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            res.status(500);
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        res.status(201);
        return "Success";
});
```

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you want to get a handle on the InputStream without reading from it?

Comment: I will be reading from it. More specifically, my app is a proxy where I want to connect an incoming stream and pass it to a 3rd party to library which will read from the stream. The streams can be large, so I don't want my app to buffer everything in memory before the 3rd party library even calls read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your use case - potentially large file uploads read by a 3rd party library - I would bypass Spark's/Jetty's multipart support and use e.g [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/):

```
// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

// Parse the *raw* request
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request.raw());
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    InputStream stream = item.getInputStream();
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value "
            + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("File field " + name + " with file name "
            + item.getName() + " detected.");
        // Process the input stream
        ...
    }
}
```

Commons FileUpload documentation calls this the *Streaming API*, so this is probably what you are looking for (to avoid buffering the whole `InputStream` content in JVM memory).